# How to redirect in expressjs while passing data to the frontend?

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

I need your help because I am new to nodejs with expressjs. I have a form that the user filled in, at the end I redirect it to another page with res.redirect ('/'). But I also want to send data to the frontend at the same time and the res.redirect () method doesn't seem to allow it.

Can you help me?

thank you very much

```
exports.signup = (req, res) =>{


bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
.then(hash =>{
  const user = new userSchema({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    nom: req.body.nom,
    prenom: req.body.prenom,
    sexe: req.body.sexe,
    date_naissance: req.body.date_naissance,
    telephone: req.body.telephone,
    nationalite: req.body.nationalite,
    pays: req.body.pays,
    lieudit: req.body.lieudit,
    numero_voie: req.body.numero_voie,
    type_voie: req.body.type_voie,
    ville: req.body.ville,
    code_postal: req.body.code_postal,
    code_iso_adresse: req.body.code_iso_address,
    numero_id: req.body.numero_id,
    id_type: req.body.id_type,
    date_delivrance: req.body.date_delivrance,
    profession: req.body.profession,
    account:{
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        dateCreation: Date.now()
    },
    email:req.body.email,
    password: hash

  });

  user.save()
  .then(data =>{
    console.log(data);
    
    res.redirect("/main");// I want to send data with the redirection
  })
  
  .catch(error=>console.log(error));

    
 })
 .catch(error=>console.log(error));

 
}
```

r code here